# FTP upload files Python

Tags: python, ftp

I am trying to upload file from windows server to a unix server (basically trying to do FTP). I have used the code below

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ftplib
import os
filename = "MyFile.py"
ftp = ftplib.FTP("xx.xx.xx.xx")
ftp.login("UID", "PSW")
ftp.cwd("/Unix/Folder/where/I/want/to/put/file")
os.chdir(r"\\windows\folder\which\has\file")
ftp.storbinary('RETR %s' % filename, open(filename, 'w').write)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Windows\folder\which\has\file\MyFile.py", line 11, in <module>
    ftp.storbinary('RETR %s' % filename, open(filename, 'w').write)
  File "windows\folder\Python\lib\ftplib.py", line 466, in storbinary
    buf = fp.read(blocksize)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Also all contents of `MyFile.py` got deleted .

Can anyone advise what is going wrong.I have read that ftp.storbinary is used for uploading files using FTP.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are trying to store a **non-binary file** (like a text file) try setting it to read mode instead of write mode.

```
ftp.storlines("STOR " + filename, open(filename, 'rb'))
```

for a **binary file** (anything that cannot be opened in a text editor) open your file in read-binary mode

```
ftp.storbinary("STOR " + filename, open(filename, 'rb'))
```

also if you plan on using the ftp lib you should probably go through a tutorial, I'd recommend this [article](http://effbot.org/librarybook/ftplib.htm) from effbot.

Comment: the contents of MyFile.py  don't get deleted . But I am still egtting the error.

Comment: Using storlines assumes that myfile is a text file. For other files (images, movies, archives, basically anything that you cannot open in a text editor and read) you should use storbinary and open the file with 'rb' instead of just 'r

Comment: according to http://bugs.python.org/issue6822 non-binary files should also be opened with 'rb' flag, but after that still uploaded with `storlines()`. just faced that problem with 'r' and 'Type str doesn't support the buffer AP' exception for the link provided.

Comment: hello @john, How about if I want to move the wav file instead of binary and text file, May I know how can I move the wav file to FTP server?

Comment: @Susan I believe a wav file is a binary file.

Comment: Thank you @John. Yes I can move the wav file using binary format to the FTP server.

Answer (score 9):

Combined both suggestions. Final answer being

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ftplib
import os
filename = "MyFile.py"
ftp = ftplib.FTP("xx.xx.xx.xx")
ftp.login("UID", "PSW")
ftp.cwd("/Unix/Folder/where/I/want/to/put/file")
os.chdir(r"\\windows\folder\which\has\file")
myfile = open(filename, 'r')
ftp.storlines('STOR ' + filename, myfile)
myfile.close()
```

Comment: Using storlines assumes that myfile is a text file. For other files (images, movies, archives, basically anything that you cannot open in a text editor and read) you should use storbinary and open the file with 'rb' instead of just 'r'

Comment: At least in the current version, you need to open the file in binary mode ('rb') to send it, otherwise you get an error. EDIT: didn't realize someone had already said this ^

Answer (score 3):

try making the file an object, so you can close it at the end of the operaton.

```
myfile = open(filename, 'w')
ftp.storbinary('RETR %s' % filename, myfile.write)
```

and at the end of the transfer

```
 myfile.close()
```

this might not solve the problem, but it may help.

Answer (score 0):

**ftplib** [supports the use of context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP) so you can make it even simpler as such

```
    with ftplib.FTP('ftp_address', 'user', 'pwd') as ftp, open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        ftp.storbinary(f'STOR {file_path.name}', file)
        ...
```

This way you are robust against both file and ftp issues without having to insert try/except/finally blocks. And well, it's pythonic.

PS: since it uses f-strings is python >= 3.6 only but can easily be modified to use the old .format() syntax